# Addition ASCII in c++

Tags: c++

I would like to change my char variable.

```
using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    char q;
    q='b';
    char c=127;
    //cout << (int)q  << endl<< static_cast<int>('z');
    char d= static_cast<char>(static_cast<int>((static_cast<int>('z') +19)));
    cout << (int)d << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Intupt:

```
-115
```

Why after addition variable assigned -115?

Comment: `char` is evidently signed on your platform, so 'z'+19 = 122+19, which overflows (because it's greater than 127) and becomes -115.

Comment: So, Should I use other type? Which one?

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to do, but if you want 8 bit values in the range 0..255 then use `unsigned char` or, better, `uint8_t`. You can then get rid of all those nasty casts too.

Comment: What do you expect the program to do?

Comment: I think the information you're missing is that whether `char` is signed or not is implementation-dependent. (BTW: `char d = 'z' + 19;` should produce the same result but slightly more concisely.)

Comment: Also, you don't really need to use that many `static_cast`s.

Comment: I would like to programme back at the beginning of ASCII. I mean (b=127 +1 = 128, but 127 is max so b=1); But Why -115? How it count?

Comment: Because the range of signed `char` is -128 to 127. As you do the addition you're surpassing the range back and forth between negatives and positive values.

Comment: @diego9403: ASCII-7 is a 7-bit encoding. `char`is a 8-bit data type (on your system). The width of `char` is fixed for a system and doesn't change with the character encoding you use (or assume). If you want it to wrap around at 128, you need to program that manually (`c &= 0x7f;`).

Answer (score 1):

On your platform, `char` is an 8 bit `signed` 2's complement type. You are actually overflowing this type and the behaviour of overflowing a `signed` integral type is **undefined** in C++. **Don't do it**.

Notes:

1. 8 bit is mandated by the standard.
2. `char` can be `unsigned` or `signed.`
3. If `unsigned` it *must* have the range [0, 255], and 255 + 1 will be 0. Overflow for an `unsigned` type **is** defined.
4. If `signed` it *can* either have the range -128 to +127 *or* -127 to +127. The latter range (1's complement) is not allowed from C++14. (Interestingly that's not a breaking change since a difference in moving from 1's to 2's complement would only be observable in a malformed program such as yours, if at all!)

A simple remedy? Use `unsigned char`.

Comment: How I can increase range of char or string? Is this possible?

Comment: You can consider `std::wstring` but it may not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

`122 + 19 = 141 --> 1000 1101` binary

type char here might be 8 bits signed int,so the first bit '1' is its sign bit.

`1000 1101` is what it's like in the computer memory.

But computers usually use *ones-complement code* to present negative number.

The *true code* of `1000 1101` is `1111 0011`,int the same way,the first '1' is its sign bit, so `1111 0011` is exactly `-115` in 10base

Comment: 2's complement `signed char` is pretty much universal these days.

Comment: i'm sorry. When I said 'ones-complement code' I mean '2's complement'.I just don't konw what's the correct expression in English.